# Outlook - Get Daily Reminder of upcoming Event

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016, reminder

In Outlook 2016 I want to have a daily reminder for an event  which tells me the days left until the date of the event is reached.

Does someone found a solution for this specific need?

Comment: What research have you done? Have you tried anything yet? Have you seen this - [Create Countdown Calendar in Microsoft Outlook](http://www.outlook-tips.net/how-to/create-countdown-calendar/)?

Comment: I have searched for it but I only found kind of solutions for tasks. This solution seems inconvenient to me. Am I right that this blogpost suggests to create new events for each day? You are maybe quite unlucky when the date changes.